# When to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_RETAIN_IN_RECENTS?

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-stack

I am trying to familiarize myself with intent flags, and I want to understand FLAG_ACTIVITY_RETAIN_IN_RECENTS. I have read the documentation and it seems like if this flag is set when calling an Activity, if the user presses the back button or that Activity is finished(), it still remains on the stack. Is this interpretation accurate? If not, what is this flag used for?

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have read the documentation and it seems like if this flag is set
>   when calling an Activity, if the user presses the back button or that
>   Activity is finished(), it still remains on the stack.

No, the Activity will not remain on the stack, but its entry will be shown in the recent task list, you can click on that entry to re-launch this Activity just as you re-launch your application.

Comment: thank you for this explanation. I have a better understanding. I will experiment more with it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

**Another Usage in OverviewScreen:**
If you want to retain a task in the overview screen, even if its activity has finished, pass the FLAG_ACTIVITY_RETAIN_IN_RECENTS flag in the addFlags() method of the Intent that launches the activity.

```
private Intent newDocumentIntent() {
final Intent newDocumentIntent = new Intent(this, NewDocumentActivity.class);
newDocumentIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
  android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RETAIN_IN_RECENTS);
newDocumentIntent.putExtra(KEY_EXTRA_NEW_DOCUMENT_COUNTER, incrementAndGet());
return newDocumentIntent;
```

}

To achieve the same effect, set the  attribute  android:autoRemoveFromRecents to false. The default value is true for document activities, and false for regular activities. Using this attribute overrides the FLAG_ACTIVITY_RETAIN_IN_RECENTS flag